# Twitter + Camel Using HTTPS / SSL 2.15.1

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, twitter4j

I am using *Camel-Twitter 2.15.1 plugin*. The document says to set below code for enabling SSL:

```
useSSL=true
```

But when I do, So it fails to resolve the endpoint with error:

> Unknown parameters=[{useSSL=true}]

Comment: Improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is mandatory now with twitter. They changed their APIs to require this. So in never Camel releases we upgrade twitter4j and the option `useSSL` has been removed as that is always enabled.

I am removing the option in the documentation.

Comment: I tested using version 2.15.1 and I get a 403 error with the following message from twitter  "message - SSL is required , code - 92". The latest version I could find it working was for 2.13.0 where I explicitly specify useSSL=true.